# How to parse returned XML from SOAP request - jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, soap

I haven't dealt with xml in this format before, w/no tag name. There may be more or less nodes returned, so I can't count them. There may be one or two after, so I can't count from end. I need to find the  who's value is result. From there find the 's text.

The returned data is this:

```
<pre><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
    <ns1:demosetupResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/">
    <demosetupReturn xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xsi:type="ns2:Map">
    <item xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
      <key xsi:type="soapenc:string">DemoUName</key>
      <value xsi:type="soapenc:string"></value>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
      <key xsi:type="soapenc:string">DemoPass</key>
      <value xsi:type="soapenc:string"></value>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
      <key xsi:type="soapenc:string">FutAcct</key>
      <value xsi:type="soapenc:string"></value>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
      <key xsi:type="soapenc:string">FxAcct</key>
      <value xsi:type="soapenc:string"></value>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
      <key xsi:type="soapenc:string">UUID</key>
      <value xsi:type="soapenc:string"></value>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
      <key xsi:type="soapenc:string">Result</key>
      <value xsi:type="soapenc:string">Error: Duplicate user account!</value>
    </item>
  </demosetupReturn>
</ns1:demosetupResponse>
```

Relevant part of my PHP cURL script:

```
f(curl_exec($soap_do) === false) {
        $err = 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($soap_do);
        curl_close($soap_do);
        print $err;
    } else {
        $result = curl_exec($soap_do);
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($result);
        // print_r($xml_post_string);
    }
    curl_close($soap_do);
```

Comment: Why can't you just use a jQuery selector like normal?

Comment: I can't get "(key).val('Result').next(value).text()" to do anything

Comment: Have you looked at: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Comment: Yes, still not close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XPath to extract the main body of the SOAP message ( I think in this case it is the `<demosetupReturn xml...` element.  And then use SimpleXML to iterate over the `<item>` elements and create an output array of the key/value pairs.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
$body = $xml->xpath("//soapenv:Body//demosetupReturn")[0];
$output = [];
foreach ( $body as $item)  {
    $output[(string)$item->key] = (string)$item->value;
}
print_r($output);
```

Comment: I don't think they're using php.

Comment: Updated question to show my PHP output. Is it better to do it in the PHP vs JS?

Comment: If you're retrieving it with curl in php, then it would be better to parse it in php.

Comment: I have yet to get that working... any help is appreciated

Comment: Is there any reason you are using curl and not SOAPClient?

Comment: I've added some more code which might help in getting the curl to work.

Comment: Curl was working with my code, and is working with yours - no change. Im using curl because I have to submit this to another end point before I get to the SOAP part. It's a mess. To clarify, I meant I am yet to be able to parse it in php - the curl worked before.

Comment: Sorry - if you pass $result into the above code, see if that outputs a set of results.

Comment: @NigelRen - that is awesome. I put it in the else clause of the curl function. It output an array of the xml nodes. I will try and target that in the jQuery .ajax success handler, would I have to convert that back to json?

Comment: echo json_encode($output); works awesome. I know how to use json!